# Paperclip::Error (There was an error processing the thumbnail

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-uploading

Paperclip::Error in RegistrationsController#update There was an error processing the thumbnail.

I'm Running `Rails 4.2.6`

and `paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"`

My application controller file is:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
 def create
 @news = News.new(news_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @news.save
     format.html { redirect_to news_url, notice: 'News post was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @news }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @news.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end

 private
 def news_params
   params.require(:news).permit(:topic, :header, :content, :link, :image)
 end
end
```

My news model is:

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :image, presence: true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { thumb: "64x64#", small: "100x100#", med: "150x150#", large: "200x200# -adaptive-resize" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

And my database migration for paperclip is:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToNews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :news do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :news, :image
  end
end
```

Database Schema:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160809173534) do

  create_table "news", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "topic",              limit: 255
    t.string   "header",             limit: 255
    t.string   "content",            limit: 255
    t.string   "link",               limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name",    limit: 255
    t.string   "image_content_type", limit: 255
    t.integer  "image_file_size",    limit: 4
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
end
```

When I `rake db:migrate` this and then try to use it I get the `Paperclip::Error in NewsController#create` `There was an error processing the thumbnail for dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-29993-12b0k3n`.

Full error:

```
  Started POST "/news" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-09 13:47:40 -0400
Processing by NewsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LQOcaS5Nfm63jIBRxjrDrjjrO/3yvKqdAgiwllPsyuZ2gQNbq4USbc+G5Nr6JuBqYZQdO6lFTHBdretDEk3Xrg==", "news"=>{"topic"=>"AutoCAD", "header"=>"News header 1", "content"=>"something should work eventually.", "link"=>"link here", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd568e25028 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/RackMultipart20160809-47024-131c2mr.jpg>, @original_filename="blockhead.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"news[image]\"; filename=\"blockhead.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create News"}
  Linkpost Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `linkposts`.* FROM `linkposts`  ORDER BY title
  Admin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE `admins`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `admins`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-yckinl.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x64" -crop "64x64+0+0" +repage '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/62af5247d7ae99288c3db01615055e6c20160809-47024-1vtevvl'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x100" -crop "100x100+0+0" +repage '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/62af5247d7ae99288c3db01615055e6c20160809-47024-1ndlv2i'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x150" -crop "150x150+0+0" +repage '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/62af5247d7ae99288c3db01615055e6c20160809-47024-1dpm4bl'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200x200#" '/var/folders/y5/brmnsb2n4f5_mkpmmn_ll_280000gn/T/62af5247d7ae99288c3db01615055e6c20160809-47024-q1w9zr'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 815ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Paperclip::Error (There was an error processing the thumbnail for dfc9ea4994791a9884f662cfa4333da420160809-47024-t1m52a):
  app/controllers/news_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

I previously had an attribute of the news class called image, not sure if that messes anything up?

It seems like it's a database problem, since if I do a rake db:setup it works fine. But, I don't want to wipe my database, so that's not an option, since `db:setup` runs a `db:schema:load` this will delete data on the server.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you then change the :image to :picture and work with that? But I suggest not keeping both. Just maybe better to remove previous :image column first. Then run rails paperclip news :image again.

Comment: @loloso I'll try that, thanks. How should I go about removing the `:image`? Should I go through mysql directly in the terminal? Or use a rails migration to remove the column(which I've never done, but heard about)?

Comment: Use rails g migration remove_image_from_news image:attachment (or whatever the image was -check db schema), which will generate a migration in the folder db/migrate. Check to make sure it says remove column from news( it's news right??) . Then rake db:migrate. Then check schema to make sure news table doesn't have image column. Then run the paperclip generator that I have u above. Writing in phone now so hard to show you how exactly the migration looks like but let me know if you have trouble.

Comment: @loloso Still getting the same `Paperclip::Error` unfortunately...

Comment: can you post the full error?

Comment: @loloso I've posted an update to my original post with the full error.

Comment: do you have imagemagick installed and everything? also it would be better to chat

Comment: @loloso I do have imagemagick installed. I ran through the tutorial on the paperclip git page as well as a youtube video tutorial of someone doing it as well. I'm not sure why it's not working... We can chat, I can't start a chat though since my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: ill start it! can you be online at all?

Comment: @loloso I'm not sure.

Comment: well i think they will move us to chat if we keep writing here. i never use it but its easier to exchnage

Comment: can you post schema table news that you have right now?

Comment: also try this really fast for me: replace paperclip 5 in  gemfile with this version:      gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.5'       and let me know if it works.

Comment: @loloso I changed the gem version, didn't fix anything. I've also posted the schema in the original post.

Comment: oh oh..... in your create action in your controller change                         "@news" to @new.... i know it might sounds strange but rails works like this ...you are creating an instance of the class News and it should be singular not plural! totally missed that but that is a big mistake

Comment: @loloso I made the changes to make that not plural. I'm still getting the paperclip processing error though. :(

Comment: same error? or different? post it all.

Comment: Same error, though I feel like I'm confused now with what should be plural and what should not be. Do you want to join me on [gitter.im](https://gitter.im/rails/rails)? Might be easier to chat there?

Answer (score 0):

In the `news` model changed this line:

`has_attached_file :image, styles: { thumb: "64x64#", small: "100x100#", med: "150x150#", large: "200x200# -adaptive-resize" }`

To this:

`has_attached_file :image, styles: { thumb: "64x64#", small: "100x100#", med: "150x150>", large: "200x200>" }`

I'm guessing the `-adaptive-resize` messes things up, I'll have to find a different way of resizing the image without distorting it.